# Get all controls from composite for a specific control type 

Tags: java

how do i get an specific control type (e.g. all buttons) from a single composite inside a swt page?

Regards
mmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [getComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29) and the use the instanceOf keyword as shown [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm).

```
Component[] components = this.getComponents();
List<Component> buttons = new ArrayList<Component>();

for (Component component : components)
{
    if (component instanceof JButton)
    {
        buttons.add(component);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add them to a collection when they're built, or use [getComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29) on your top-level container to get all the components in your UI. Then provide accessor methods like `getAllButtons()` that give a reference back to a collection of controls by type, for convenience.

Depending on your needs, you might have something like the following list of methods

```
getAllButtons()        // returns an array, LinkedList, or other collection of all Buttons
addButton(Button)      // adds a specific, new Button to the global list of Buttons
removeButton(Button)   // removes a specific, existing Button from the global list
removeAllButtons()     // clears the global list of Buttons
```

Repeat for any component/control types you need to support.